# Where to store the intermediate data

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to develop an application which fetches data from an external system. The data returned is huge like a List of 10k to 20k objects or more. Now the user can click on info button and the data matching from that earlier list needs to be displayed to the user. Retrieving data from external system is costly. So what options do I have to store that list. I am using Spring Boot framework.
I guess session should not be used.

Comment: Either use a Cache or store that data somewhere else (not in-memory) like a database, a file, ...

Answer (score 0):

Well 20k objects in a list may NOT be too much to just keep in memory.  That would depend on the size of each object.  For example, if each object only uses 1k I'd say using 20k in memory is likely fine and would keep things nice and fast.

If it is too much to just leave in RAM, then your best bet for performance is something local, like a file on disk.  Anything that needs to call out over the wire to another system is likely to incur a bigger performance hit.  However...

If you are in a hosted environment like, say, GCP, then network calls within that environment may be very fast.  In this case you could consider other options.  In the case of GCP you might look at Google's hosted Memcached service.  That would likely get you very close to in-memory performance (Memcached is, in fact, in memory, just not yours, and is designed to hold huge amounts of data in-memory).

Comment: If I plan to use Redis cache. Is it free to be used in an enterprise app?

Comment: Redis itself is open source software under the BSD license.  I am not a lawyer, but that likely means it is free to use for most use-cases.If you are asking about a hosted instance of Redis it would depend on the hosting party.  I am also not affiliated with Google and have not actually used the GCP hosted Redis or Memcached products, but Google does offer hosted Redis ([https://cloud.google.com/memorystore?](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore?)).

Comment: GCP cost is all based on usage.  Google does have a free tier for most things that is typically more than enough for small or personal or school projects, etc.